# Controlling WCF Message Body serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, controls, message

I need to create a WCF service that will emulate some third-party service. That service has very complicated messages and wrappers for them, so I will simplify them in description.
I have WSDL of that service and created proxy class. But here the first problem occurs: **all methods in proxy have**
    `[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]`
So it is impossible to create WCF service with many methods: each for one method in proxy because every method must have unique Action. I think that third-party service has one method that handles all requests. And I created such method with needed KnownType attributes on RequestTypeBase and ResponceTypeBase. All proxy-class methods have one parameter of type, derived from RequestTypeBase.
**And here is the main problem and question:** when WCF service tries to deserialize message body, it throws an exception saying that expected elementName is "Process" (the name of my mega-method that processes all requests) but existing elementName is "RequestType1" (the name class with data that must be passed to "Process" method as parameter). *So how can I receive such message?? Is there some attribute in WCF to not require the methodName as root of Message body? And I even not understand for what does WCF need that MethodName there if he already knows what method is called? Looks like redundancy with action specification.*

Maybe simple MessabeBody example that is successfully processing by WCF, will help to understand what I mean:

```
<s:Body>
  <TestMethod xmlns="someNamespace">
    <x>1</x>
    <str>param2</str>
  </TestMethod>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: Oh, as often happens, good question is a half of answer =).
I found attribute that helped: [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute]
Add it to interface-method of WCF service

Comment: Oh no, I think XmlSerializerFormatAttribute does nothing good - XmlSerializer simply not throws an exception that element "Process" not found, but it results in calling that method with null as parameter =(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip WCF deserialization completely on the service side by using the "universal service contract":

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUniversalRequestResponseContract
{
    [OperationContract(Action="*", ReplyAction="*")]
    Message ProcessMessage(Message msg);
}
```

and then handle deserialization yourself working with the Message instance received.

If you are writing a stub emulation of some external service for testing purposes (I'm guessing), that is a good approach anyway because you can control exactly what is sent in the response.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it will help! I tried almost the same method but instead of Message parameter I used RequestTypeBase