# Returning a custom formatted SOAP message from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a requirement where a method call on a WCF service has to return a SOAP message in the format below:

```
<soap:Body>
<m:RequestProcessed xmlns:m=" ">
<m:Status>OK</m:Status>
<m:UID>subfolder name</m:UID>
</m: RequestProcessed >
</soap:Body>
```

Can this be done with Faults, if so please give some pointers on where to look.
If not then what is the alternate?

Appreciate your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I had very similar question: [Controlling WCF Message Body serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452402/controlling-wcf-message-body-serialization)
Probably the answer will help you too (please note it requires WCF 4).

The alternative is writing directly to the response streem even without need to work with abstract Message object. This approach is described in this thread: [WCF 4 REST - Acquiring the underlying response stream object for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630083/wcf-4-rest-acquiring-the-underlying-response-stream-object-for-writing)