# Getting started with user defined SOAP message in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning a custom formatted SOAP message from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372957/returning-a-custom-formatted-soap-message-from-wcf)

before I post my question here's what I have practiced and know:

1. Create a WCF service library
2. Host it in Windows service
3. Accessed the service from a client

Now for a real world situation.
I have a requirement where the client will send a SOAP message like so:

```
<soap:Body>
 <m:CreateFolder xmlns:m=" ">
  <m:UID>0124567890</m:UID>
  <m:Owner>10.25</m:Owner>
  <m:User>7.375</m:User>
  <m:Developer>15.125</m:Developer>
  <m:SupName>MySup.sup</m:SupName>
 </m: CreateFolder>
```

I thought that WCF handles the SOAP part and I can straight away implement a method with name CreateFolder and having the params UID, Owner, User, Developer and SupName.

I have no clue what the client will be meaning all I know is that the service will be consumed by a web based interface.
Oh btw the service also has to return a message in a format like above.

How do I write a WCF service that will take this 'SOAP' and process it?